# Comparing an arbitrary number of lists element by element

Tags: python, list, compare, sublist

I have a bunch of lists of the form:

```
list1 = [4,[14,13,12,11,10]]
list2 = [4,[13,12,11,10,9 ]]
list3 = [4,[5 ,4 ,3 ,2 ,1 ]]
list4 = [3,[14,14,14,13,1 ]]
list5 = [3,[14,14,14,12,11]]
list6 = [2,[14,14,13,13,12]]
list7 = [1,[14,14,13,12,11]]
list8 = [0,[14,13,12,11, 9]]
```

I need to compare these lists using the following comparisons:
1) Compare the first sublist. And return all of the lists that contain the largest sublist value. So in the above case, I would return list1, list2, list3 because they all have a first sublist value of 4.
2) Then I would compare the second sublist (which is the list inside the list)
This comparison would be element by element in each of these lists.
Example: Look at lists 1,2,3. List 1's first element is 14, list 2's first element is 13, and list 3's first element is 5. So that would lead to returning list 1, because it had a higher value than list 2 and list 3.

But consider this instead:

```
list1 = [4,[14,13,12,11,10]]
list2 = [4,[14,13,11,10,8 ]]
```

list1 and list2 both have 4 as the first sublist, so I would grab them. And next I would look at the second sublist (again the list), and compare element by element until one list is greater than another. So here I would compare 14 == 14, 13 == 13, and finally 12 > 11, so list1 would be returned.

I still need to do this with arbitrary numbers of lists and element transversals.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You're question is not too clear...but try using a function with `*args` to deal with the arbitrary amount. I can't help with the function because I don't really know what you want when you say "and how many elements in I have to go find a difference I will also not know"

Comment: What's the expected output? Are you trying to sort the lists based on the contents?

Comment: Are these all separate variables? Why are these not values in a dictionary or list instead? Are these items sorted on the first value if these are lists inside a list (instead of separate variables)?

Comment: Martijn, These are all inside of a dictionary indexed just by an integer, so list1 really corresponds to mydict[1]. And in the long run I want to return the dictionary key that corresponds to what list gets returned, but That's the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to sort the lists based on their content, then the comparison behavior you describe is what Python uses by default, so you can just use Python's built-in list-sorting to achieve this.

```
>>> import random, pprint
>>> all_lists = [[4, [14, 13, 12, 11, 10]],
...              [4, [13, 12, 11, 10, 9]],
...              [4, [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]],
...              [3, [14, 14, 14, 13, 1]],
...              [3, [14, 14, 14, 12, 11]],
...              [2, [14, 14, 13, 13, 12]],
...              [1, [14, 14, 13, 12, 11]],
...              [0, [14, 13, 12, 11, 9]]]
>>> random.shuffle(all_lists)
>>> pprint.pprint(all_lists)
[[2, [14, 14, 13, 13, 12]],
 [4, [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]],
 [4, [13, 12, 11, 10, 9]],
 [3, [14, 14, 14, 12, 11]],
 [1, [14, 14, 13, 12, 11]],
 [4, [14, 13, 12, 11, 10]],
 [3, [14, 14, 14, 13, 1]],
 [0, [14, 13, 12, 11, 9]]]
>>> all_lists.sort(reverse=True)
>>> pprint.pprint(all_lists)
[[4, [14, 13, 12, 11, 10]],
 [4, [13, 12, 11, 10, 9]],
 [4, [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]],
 [3, [14, 14, 14, 13, 1]],
 [3, [14, 14, 14, 12, 11]],
 [2, [14, 14, 13, 13, 12]],
 [1, [14, 14, 13, 12, 11]],
 [0, [14, 13, 12, 11, 9]]]
```

The 'largest' list will end up in `all_lists[0]`.

---

**Update**

If they're in a dictionary, and you just want to find the key of the largest, then something like this should work...

```
my_dict = {1: [2, [14, 14, 13, 13, 12]],
           2: [4, [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]],
           3: [4, [13, 12, 11, 10, 9]],
           4: [3, [14, 14, 14, 12, 11]],
           5: [1, [14, 14, 13, 12, 11]],
           6: [4, [14, 13, 12, 11, 10]],
           7: [3, [14, 14, 14, 13, 1]],
           8: [0, [14, 13, 12, 11, 9]]}

key = max(my_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
print 'The largest list has key: %r' % key
```

...which prints...

```
The largest list has key: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the builtin `max` to do the comparisons for you, so it'll take the first item, then compare lists naturally... Then just take the index of the list as the reference back to your dict or whatever it is you have...

```
print 'list {}'.format(max((v, i) for i, v in enumerate((list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7, list8), start=1))[1])
```